MAUI VScode SourceLink - Debug External source
Does someone managed to make SourceLink work on VSCode in a MAUI Project?
My environment: .Net 8 MAUI  VScode MacOs.
I tried to enable JustMyCode in settings, I tried various configuration in launch.json without success...

Thanks but I'm trying to switch from VS For Mac to VSCode and the link you share are for VS For Windows. It's difficult to know if there's a support or not in my context
